# Is there a Terminal command to update minimatch MAC OSX

Tags: node.js, bash, macos

Can anyone suggest the proper command to write on Terminal window in OSX to update minimatch script. I tried the following:

```
$ sudo npm update -g minimatch
```

It looks like commands got executed with no result messages . Then later checked 
with the command:

```
$ sudo minimatch --version
```

it else end in a error:

```
-bash: minimatch: command not found
```

I don't know exactly , but i feel something is wrong. Could anyone tell me if anything wrong made in above 2 syntax.

I tried a lot searching for articles , but not a one specific to my problem . Thanks ahead for your advice to find a fix for my problem

Thanks!

Comment: `minimatch` doesn't install a CLI tool, it's a Node module that you can use from your own code.

Comment: You shouldn't sudo all the things either. https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: Seeing every post here on SO says to use `sudo` with the `npm update` like commands on osx.

Comment: Command to update minimatch
`$ npm update -g minimatch`
Check the updated version of minimatch
`$ npm view minimatch version`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, it will update minimatch at the same time:

```
$ npm install npm -g
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ sudo npm install -g minimatch
```

worked for me !

Comment: Hi @akkolad ,I tried your suggestions and following is the result:  'code'        Rubins-MacBook-Pro:TRAVEL_GUIDE Pratik$ sudo npm install -g minimatch
Password:
minimatch@3.0.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/minimatch
└── brace-expansion@1.1.5 (balanced-match@0.4.1, concat-map@0.0.1)
Rubins-MacBook-Pro:TRAVEL_GUIDE Pratik$ sudo npm minimatch --version
2.15.5    , could you please tell me if minimatch is properly updated